# File line to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python

So, I want to write a file line to a dictionary of tuples.

Each line of a file is set up so a name matches a group of data.
name,a,b,c,d each could be a different length in each set of data.

```
name: a: b: c: d
```

I want to create a dictionary that is set up like the following..

```
dict = {name : (a,b,c,d)}
```

how would i do that?

Comment: And how are you doing on your attempts?

Comment: I'm not sure on to store something up to a certain character(
":")

Comment: Is the file format something that's forced on you? If not, have you considered using JSON instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to split the line properly:

```
line = 'name: a: b: c: d\n'
pieces = line.split(':')
name = pieces[0]
tup = tuple(x.strip() for x in pieces[1:])
```

From here, it's just a matter of putting this in a loop and adding the `name`, `tup` to a dictionary which I trust you can do.

Comment: Thanks, i got it from here!